# Why does the same color display as different colors on barbuttonItems?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I am working on an iOS project at the moment and I've encountered an annoying problem.

When I set the same color to two different `UIBarButtonItem`s, they display different colors.

Seems very strange, any thoughts?

Code:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]


UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target: self action: @selector(save)];

saveButton.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xFF8100);


UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target: self action: @selector(backButtonPressed)];
backButton.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xFF8100);


self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the system provided Save button (UIBarButtonSystemItemSave) is tinted differently from other buttons, to indicate the confirming or saving nature of the button.

[image]

If you want to have a Save button with the same color, you could use a regular button and set the title to "Save".

```
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                    initWithTitle:@"Save" 
                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                           target:self 
                                           action:@selector(save)];
saveButton.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xFF8100);
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly! Still strange that an orange tint becomes bright yellow.. But good to know how it works.